# Launching a Silverlight App from a desktop app and vice versa

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have been asked to investigate the possibility of launching our companies current desktop app from a silverlight app we may develop. Would it be possible to launch a desktop app from a silverlight app (both in browser and out of browser) and vice versa, i.e. launch the silverlight OOB app from the winforms desktop app?
If so, how would I go about doing this?

If this is possible, I assume it would be possible to launch 3rd Party Applications as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you would need to install the application as an OOB application with elevated trust. In that scenario, you could use COM interop to get a shell and launch a process. If you want to launch another Silverlight application, look into SLLauncher.exe as that is the host that is used to launch OOB applications.